# Count how many seconds did the user hover an element using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

just need a little help here. My problem is, how can I count the seconds when i hover a specific element. Like for example when I hover a button, how can i count the seconds did i stayed in that button after I mouseout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution using `setInterval`. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WqeAD/)

```
var counter = 0;
var myInterval =null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(e){
        counter = 0;
        myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            ++counter;
        }, 1000);
    },function(e){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        alert(counter);
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not account for any values between 0 and 999 milliseconds for any second.. Instead you can set an interval to 30 milliseconds and divide by that number before outputting the value.

Comment: A bit better which will account for that http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WqeAD/1/

Comment: @Sushanth-- Ofcourse I could have done that. But OP mentioned 'Count how many seconds' not milliseconds, so for 0-999 milliseconds its 0 second

Comment: @anu "1.5 seconds" is still a quantity of seconds.

Comment: Thanks that's what i need. Thanks for the suggestions and ideas for my question guys.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I am unable to understand the downvote. Is incomplete and incorrect answer are the same thing. I guess my answer is not factually incorrect

Comment: Hello how can i identify if counter is greater than to 3 because what i did is after the clearInter(myInterval); i added a comparison operator. if(counter > 3){alert(counter);} but nothing happen

Comment: I downvoted it, because IMHO it's a poor answer.  There's no need to use a timer, just record the timestamp value that's _in the event object_!

Comment: @Alnitak Yes its not an optimal solution and for that reason I started this post with the words 'An alternate solution'. Thanks for pointing it out by the way

Answer (score 2):

A simple example

```
var timer;
// Bind the mouseover and mouseleave events
$('button').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        // set the variable to the current time
        timer = Date.now();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // get the difference
        timer = Date.now() - timer;  
         console.log( parseFloat(timer/1000) + " seconds");
        timer = null;        
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hjTv7/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

How about this quick plugin I just knocked out, which will work on multiple elements, and without using any global variables:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hoverTimer = function() {
        return this.on({
            'mouseenter.timer': function(ev) {
                 $(this).data('enter', ev.timeStamp);
             },
             'mouseleave.timer': function(ev) {
                 var enter = $(this).data('enter');
                 if (enter) {
                     console.log(this, ev.timeStamp - enter);
                 }
              }
         });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Actually *disabling* the functionality is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/r9XkX/

IMHO, anything using a timer for this is a poor implementation.  It's perfectly trivial to record the time without needing to use an (inaccurate) timer event to "count" seconds.  Heck, the event object even has the current time in it, as used above.

Answer (score 1):

This is exam:

```
var begin = 0;
var end = 0;

$('#btn').hover(function () {
   begin = new Date().getTime();
});

$('#btn').leave(function () {
   end = new Date().getTime();
   sec = (end - begin) / 1000;
   alert(sec);
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the mouseout function of hover ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it would be the [event.timeStamp](http://api.jquery.com/event.timeStamp/) method :

```
var initial_hover, exit_hover;
$('#ele').hover(
    function(event){
        initial_hover = event.timeStamp
        console.log(initial_hover);
    },
    function(event){
        exit_hover = event.timeStamp
        $(this).html(exit_hover - initial_hover);
        console.log(exit_hover);
    }
);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjPfK/)

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with JQuery, so here's a jQuery solution.

```
$(element).on('mouseover', function(e){
    $(e.target).data('hover-start', new Date().getTime());
});

$(element).on('mouseout', function(e){
    // count the difference
    var difference = new Date().getTime() - $(e.target).data('hover-start');
    // clean up the data
    $(e.target).data('hover-start', undefined);

    console.log('Mouse was over for', difference/1000, 'seconds');
});
```

Comment: why not use `e.timeStamp` ?!

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval and store value in variable. call the function on mouserover.

```
function mouseover(){
  var start = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    start++;
    var count = start;
  }, 1000);
}
```